# How can I monitor the ~/.local directory using Vala?

Tags: directory, local, monitor, glib, vala

I am trying to monitor the ~/.local directory according to the [Vala documentation](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.monitor_directory.html) I can monitor the home correctly. but I can't monitor the the ~/.local.

## initFileMonitor V1:

```
public void initFileMonitor(){
    try {
        string homePath = Environment.get_home_dir();
        string filePath = homePath + "/.local";
        File file = File.new_for_path(filePath);
        FileMonitor monitor = file.monitor_directory(FileMonitorFlags.NONE, null);

        print ("\nMonitoring: %s\n", file.get_path ());

        monitor.changed.connect ((src, dest, event) => {
            if (dest != null) {
                 print ("%s: %s, %s\n", event.to_string (), src.get_path (), dest.get_path ());
            } else {
                print ("%s: %s\n", event.to_string (), src.get_path ());
            }
        });
    } catch (Error err) {
        print ("Error: %s\n", err.message);
    }
}
```

#### terminal output(no error, no monitoring):

```
Monitoring: /home/srdr/.local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the file monitor is stored in a local variable it is like other variables destroyed (or in GObject terms finalised/destructed) at the end of the function call

To ensure it lives long enough you should make it a field on a class, then the FileMonitor instance is 'owned' by an instance of that class rather than each call to a specific method

Runnable demo (`valac demo.vala --pkg gio-2.0`)

```
class FileMonitorDemo {
    private FileMonitor monitor;

    public void initFileMonitor() {
        var path = Path.build_filename(Environment.get_home_dir(), ".local");
        var file = File.new_for_path(path);
        try {
            monitor = file.monitor_directory(NONE);

            message ("Monitoring: %s", file.get_path ());

            monitor.changed.connect ((src, dest, event) => {
                if (dest != null) {
                    print ("%s: %s, %s\n", event.to_string (), src.get_path (), dest.get_path ());
                } else {
                    print ("%s: %s\n", event.to_string (), src.get_path ());
                }
            });
        } catch (Error err) {
            critical ("Error: %s\n", err.message);
        }
    }
}

void main () {
    var filemon = new FileMonitorDemo();
    filemon.initFileMonitor();
    new MainLoop ().run ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually run the monitor by creating a main loop and having it wait for events:

```
new MainLoop ().run ();
```

Comment: But this is a Budgie desktop applet. I think it does not need the MainLoop.  it works fine with other directories.

Comment: The monitor is going out of scope and being destroyed if this is only part of the application.

Comment: Yes, I assume `initFileMonitor` is a method of a class extending Applet, as in the Python the file monitor should be stored in a field of that class (`self.monitor` for example), then the monitor will be 'owned' by the Applet instance and work as expected. Currently, the monitor isn't owned by anything so is destroyed at the end of the function call