# How can I monitor the "trash:///" directory using Vala?

Tags: monitoring, glib, vala, recycle-bin

I am trying to convert [budgie-trash python applet](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/experimental/blob/master/budgie-trash/src/budgie-trash/TrashApplet.py) to Vala and I am trying to monitor the "trash:///" directory according to the [Vala documentation](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.monitor_directory.html) I can monitor the home correctly. but I can't monitor the the "trash:///". The python applet working correctly for all directories.

## initialiseTrashFileMonitor V1:

```
public void initialiseTrashFileMonitor(){
    try {

        GLib.File file = GLib.File.new_for_uri("trash:///");
        GLib.FileMonitor monitor = file.monitor_directory(0, null);

        print ("\n initialiseTrashFileMonitor Monitoring: %s\n", file.get_path ());

        monitor.changed.connect ((src, dest, event) => {

            print ("\n initialiseTrashFileMonitor monitor.changed.connect \n");

            if (dest != null) {
                print ("%s: %s, %s\n", event.to_string (), src.get_path (), dest.get_path ());
            } else {
                print ("%s: %s\n", event.to_string (), src.get_path ());
            }
        });

    } catch (Error err) {
        print ("\n initialiseTrashFileMonitor Error: %s\n", err.message);
    }
}
```

#### terminal output(no error, no monitoring):

```
initialiseTrashFileMonitor Monitoring: (null)
```

I also asked that question here for this purpose : [How can I monitor the ~/.local directory using Vala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177265/how-can-i-monitor-the-local-directory-using-vala)

Comment: The last sentence would suggest this is by definition a duplicate

Comment: This issue solved by AlexB's answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194531/5994546](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51194531/5994546)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I monitor the ~/.local directory using Vala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177265/how-can-i-monitor-the-local-directory-using-vala)